# Is there a way of uploading input fields together with pdf document or image in nodejs and react? Any resource explaining the same will be appreciated

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, multer

I am developing a system that requires users to upload a document or image together with other input fields. Uploading/inserting the other input fields is success, but can't happen for file

Comment: If you want to send documents and fields in one request I believe the content type multipart/mixed should fit your needs. Using this content type you you can combine any number of different content types in one request (image, form fields, text, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget the enctype="multipart/form-data" in your form.

`<form action="/profile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="avatar" />
</form>`

I have included a working example code sandbox which you can check out here. https://codesandbox.io/s/upload-file-multer-spvyc

resource used is https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

Comment: Thanks bro. It worked though now giving the value of Fake Path in the database